# android myappadaptor filter for listview

Tags: java, android

Hi i have tried to implement the following code to my listview item. https://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/ , but i cannot get the getfilter to resolve. Mostlikely the myappadaptor doesn't have a getfilter method.

Am i going to correct way about this or should i be taking a different approach.

Thanks

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // When user changed the Text
    ScaleSelect.this.myAppAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
  }

  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
  }

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {   
  }
});
```

Here is my code so far

```
> package com.dmh.trent.scale_checker;
> 
> import android.annotation.SuppressLint; import
> android.app.ProgressDialog; import android.content.Context; import
> android.content.Intent; import android.os.AsyncTask; import
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.view.LayoutInflater; import android.view.View; import
> android.view.ViewGroup; import android.widget.BaseAdapter; import
> android.widget.EditText; import android.widget.ListView; import
> android.widget.TextView; import android.widget.Toast; import
> java.io.PrintWriter; import java.io.StringWriter; import
> java.io.Writer; import java.sql.Connection; import
> java.sql.DriverManager; import java.sql.ResultSet; import
> java.sql.Statement; import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.List;
> import android.text.Editable; import android.text.TextWatcher;
> 
> 
> public class ScaleSelect extends AppCompatActivity {
> 
>     private ArrayList<ClassListItems> itemArrayList;  //List items Array
>     private MyAppAdapter myAppAdapter; //Array Adapter
>     private ListView listView; // ListView
>     private boolean success = false; // boolean
> 
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.scale_select);
>         listView = findViewById(R.id.listView); //ListView Declaration
>         itemArrayList = new ArrayList<>(); // Arraylist Initialization
>         EditText inputSearch = findViewById(R.id.sitefiltertext);
> 
>         // Calling Async Task
>         SyncData orderData = new SyncData();
>         orderData.execute("");
> 
> 
>         inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
> 
>             @Override
>             public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
>                 // When user changed the Text
>                 ScaleSelect.this.myAppAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
>             }
> 
>             @Override
>             public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
>                                           int arg3) {
> 
> 
>             }
> 
>             @Override
>             public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
> 
>             }
>         });
> 
>     }
> 
>     // Async Task has three overrided methods,
>     @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
>     private class SyncData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
>         String msg = "Internet/DB_Credentials/Windows_FireWall_TurnOn Error, See Android Monitor in the bottom For details!";
>         ProgressDialog progress;
> 
>         @Override
>         protected void onPreExecute() //Starts the progress dailog
>         {
>             progress = ProgressDialog.show(ScaleSelect.this, "Synchronising",
>                     "ListView Loading! Please Wait...", true);
>         }
> 
>         @Override
>         protected String doInBackground(String... strings)  // Connect to the database, write query and add items to array list
>         {
>             try {
>                 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
>                 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Appconfig.connectionString,
> Appconfig.db_user, Appconfig.db_pass); //Connection Object
>                 if (conn == null) {
>                     success = false;
>                 } else {
>                     // Change below query according to your own database.
>                     String query = "SELECT companyname, companystreetname FROM site";
>                     Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
>                     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
>                     if (rs != null) // if resultset not null, I add items to itemArraylist using class created
>                     {
>                         while (rs.next()) {
>                             try {
>                                 itemArrayList.add(new ClassListItems(rs.getString("companyname")));
>                             } catch (Exception ex) {
>                                 ex.printStackTrace();
>                             }
>                         }
>                         msg = "Found";
>                         success = true;
>                     } else {
>                         msg = "No Data found!";
>                         success = false;
>                     }
>                 }
>             } catch (Exception e) {
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>                 Writer writer = new StringWriter();
>                 e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
>                 msg = writer.toString();
>                 success = false;
>             }
>             return msg;
>         }
> 
>         @Override
>         protected void onPostExecute(String msg) // disimissing progress dialoge, showing error and setting up my ListView
>         {
>             progress.dismiss();
>             Toast.makeText(ScaleSelect.this, msg + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>             if (!success) {
>             } else {
>                 try {
>                     myAppAdapter = new MyAppAdapter(itemArrayList, ScaleSelect.this);
>                     listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
>                     listView.setAdapter(myAppAdapter);
>                 } catch (Exception ignored) {
> 
>                 }
> 
>             }
>         }
>     }
> 
>     public class MyAppAdapter extends BaseAdapter         //has a class viewholder which holds
>     {
>         class ViewHolder {
>             TextView textName;
>         }
> 
>         List<ClassListItems> parkingList;
> 
>         Context context;
>         ArrayList<ClassListItems> arraylist;
> 
>         private MyAppAdapter(List<ClassListItems> apps, Context context) {
>             this.parkingList = apps;
>             this.context = context;
>             arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
>             arraylist.addAll(parkingList);
>         }
> 
>         @Override
>         public int getCount() {
>             return parkingList.size();
>         }
> 
>         @Override
>         public Object getItem(int position) {
>             return position;
>         }
> 
>         @Override
>         public long getItemId(int position) {
>             return position;
>         }
> 
>         @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
>         @Override
>         public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) // inflating the layout and initializing widgets
>         {
> 
>             View rowView = convertView;
>             ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
>             if (rowView == null) {
>                 LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
>                 rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_content, parent, false);
>                 viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
>                 viewHolder.textName = rowView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
>                 rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
>             } else {
>                 viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
>             }
>             // here setting up names and images
>             viewHolder.textName.setText(parkingList.get(position).getName() + "");
> 
>             return rowView;
>         }
>     }
```

and my xml

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     tools:context="com.dmh.trent.scale_checker.ScaleSelect">
> 
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/mainmenubuttun"
>         android:layout_width="200dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
>         android:layout_marginEnd="200dp"
>         android:onClick="mainmenubutton"
>         android:text="@string/mainmenu"
>         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
> 
>     <ListView
>         android:id="@+id/listView"
>         android:layout_width="290dp"
>         android:layout_height="241dp"
>         android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
>         android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
>         android:scrollbars="vertical"
>         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sitefiltertext" />
> 
>     <EditText
>         android:id="@+id/sitefiltertext"
>         android:layout_width="289dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
>         android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
>         android:ems="10"
>         android:hint="@string/Search"
>         android:inputType="textPersonName"
>         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" /> </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Am i going to correct way about this or should i be taking a different
>   approach.

I would recommend you not using ListView, because it is kinda deprecated now.  Use  [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) Instead. With it's adapter you can filter your list in your Activity or Fragnent like this:

```
searchField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // filter your list from your input
        filter(s.toString());
    }
});



void filter(String text){
     List<DataHolder> temp = new ArrayList();
     for(DataHolder d: displayedList){
           //or use .equal(text) with you want equal match
           //use .toLowerCase() for better matches
           if(d.getEnglish().contains(text)){
               temp.add(d);
           }
     }
     //update recyclerview Adapter with new List
     adapter.updateList(temp);
}
```

And in adapter of RecyclerView you will have **updateList** method:

```
public void updateList(List<DataHolder> list){
     currentList = list;
     notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```